# Indicators Disappear

Tags: highcharts

I have a react application which stores candlestick information in Redux where it's index is set by "symbol - timeframe".  When I set the plotOptions data to local state, I can get the chart to draw.  Now this is a live chart so when the last bar updates or a new bar updates, I can see highstock updating the plot.  The problem is when I add an indicator, the moment a new point is added or the last point updates, all indicators disappear.  Any idea why this would happen?  A few things to note, in Redux, I update the candlestick array using immer so the immutability code should be fine.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your issue on some online editor? Without seeing your code it's hard to say what could have an impact on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your exact problem but I had a similar issue with indicators hiding..

**Injected series is overriding highcharts created series.**

Are you using the method of injecting the series into wrapper props?

```js
<ChartWrapper chartOptions={this.state.chartOptions}/>
```

or this

```js
<ChartWrapper chartSeries={this.state.series}/>
```

I solved the indicators hiding by registering the addSeries event.

I replace my props series with the current charts series + the event series - the navigator series

```js
chart: { 
     events:{
          addSeries(e) {
            var series = props.chartRef.current.chart.series.map(s => s.options);
            if(series.findIndex(s => s.id == e.options.id)){
              series = series.slice(0, series.length - 1)
              series.push(e.options);           
              props.onAddIndicator(series);
              return false; //having issues with return false sometimes, touchend error fires. If dont return false there are temporary duplicate indicators
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Just register a props function on your chart wrapper

```js
onAddIndicator(series){
   this.setState({series: series});
}
```

```js
<ChartWrapper chartOptions={this.state.chartOptions} onAddIndicator={this.onAddIndicator}/>
```